# Approximating electrical consumption of configurations

Tags: power-consumption

I'm interested, are there any sites where one could find an approximation of electrical consuption, so if one has different configurations, one could approximately calculate consumption of that configuration if it worked for example, 24/7, for a full month ?

Anyone knows of anything similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the power consumption calculators that some of the PC power supply manufacturers provide? For example, [this calculator from Antec](http://www.antec.outervision.com/)? It will allow you to play around with different PC configurations and at least give you an idea of the resulting power consumption.

Comment: It'll be your CPU and GPU that will define the bulk of the load, but also bear in mind that calculating accurate 24/7 info will be tricky unless you know the average load the machine will be under and what power saving configuration you plan to run and so on. My energy monitor reports 105W at present (inc monitor and router), but that'll go up to around 190W gaming, for example.

Comment: @Gcoupe - yes, that calculator is something like I was looking for. It will be more than sufficient for first approximation, which I need. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do is buy a monitoring device that you can plugin between the device and the socket such as the following:

[image]

If you cannot find one, then try to find out as many specifications as possible - You really need Amps and Voltage.

Next, find out how much you pay in Kilowatt Hours kWh. Then take a look at this [calculator](http://www.ukpower.co.uk/tools/running_costs_electricity/), it will fill out a lot for you. In addition to the above, add how many hours you will use it and how many of the devices you have.

Last step - be scared how much it costs to run all your equipment!

Comment: Wil, thanks for your answer (nice kitchen tiles :), but I need the data for configurations which I don't yet have. Finding (A) and (V) is not easy, for most components.

Comment: At least, do you know where one could find examples of average home configuration examples.

Comment: It isn't my picture! I Googled "energy monitor"! It may be worth emailing customer support / looking at manuals but apart from that, I have no idea - sorry!